# if else statement does't work correctly

Tags: python

```
grade=['A good','B ok','C bad']
for item in grade:
    if item[0] == 'A':
        print('Excellent')
    if item[0] == 'B':
        print('Nice')
    else:
        print('Work harder')
```

I want A to just print 'Excellent' while B just print 'Nice', and c (else) print 'Work harder'. But both A and B print 'Work Harder', and C (else) doesn't print anything. What would be a way to fix this?

result

```
Excellent
Work harder
Nice
Work harder
```

Comment: Your assumption what happens when is wrong. `A` will give you "Excellent" and "Work harder", `B` leads to "Nice" and the result of `C` is "Work harder".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do this.

```
grade=['A good','B ok','C bad']
for item in grade:
    if item[0] == 'A':
        print('Excellent')
    elif item[0] == 'B':
        print('Nice')
    else:
        print('Work harder')
```

the reason it didn't work is because you were handling two of the conditions separetely not as a single unit, if you're testing multiple values always use `if - elif - else` not `if - if - else`

Answer (score 3):

You're handling `A` separately from `B` and `C`. Connect them into a single structure with `elif`:

```
elif item[0] == 'B':
```

Answer (score 2):

You need the `if-else if-else` flow here. Just change the second if to `elif`

```
    grade=['A good','B ok','C bad']
    for item in grade:
        if item[0] == 'A':
            print('Excellent')
        elif item[0] == 'B':
            print('Nice')
        else:
            print('Work harder')
```